# Как в цикле bat притормозить выполнение скрипта

Tags: cmd, bat

Можете сократить код и приостановить его, чтобы не так быстро было

```
@echo off
:2
color 0a
set MIN=0
set MAX=1
set /a A=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a B=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a C=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a D=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a E=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a F=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a G=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a H=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a I=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a J=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a AA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a BA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a CA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a DA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a EA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a FA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a GA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a HA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a IA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a JA=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a AB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a BB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a CB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a DB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a EB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a FB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a GB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a HB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a IB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a JB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a AC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a BC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a CC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a DC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a EC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a FC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a GC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a HC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a IC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768
set /a JC=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768


echo %A% %B% %C% %D% %E% %F% %G% %H% %I% %J% %AA% %BA% %CA% %DA% %EA% %FA% %GA% %HA% %IA% %JA% %AB% %BB% %CB% %DB% %EB% %FB% %GB% %HB% %IB% %JB% %A% %BC% %CC% %DC% %EC% %FC% %GC% %HC% %IC% %JC%

goto :2
```

чтото крутится в голове но не могу понять как

Comment: Вставь `pause` перед `echo` (и, если надо, ещё где-нить в середёнке). Ну или `set /a HB=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768 && timeout /T 1` там...

Comment: @Akina нет, надо чтобы выполнилась команда, притормозилась на 0.1 сек и  начала выполнятся заново

Comment: `Timeout /T 1` перед `echo` (ну или после метки) - но он умеет только целые секунды. Если надо доли - ищи аналог.

Comment: аналога в том то и дело нет. я думаю что это можно сделать через for

Comment: Ну разве что залепить for, в котором считать в какой-ить переменной от нуля до, скажем, миллиона... и подрихтовать границу до нужной паузы.